# Netlogo: Alternative turtle breed / death

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to have a population of turtles breed / die in sets instead of individually?

For example: Say for each tick I'd like one population of turtles to increase by 5 and another population to decrease by 4.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do something like this

```
ifelse your condition come here
[ ask n-of 4 breed_type_1 [ die ]
  create-breed_type_2 5
]
[ ask n-of 4 breed_type_2 [ die ]
  create-breed_type_1 5
]
```

I am not sure if my syntax is error-free.

Comment: fixed the n-of syntax for you